# How would I go about copying owner protected files?

Tags: windows-10, ownership

Currently I'm attempting to copy a file from the WindowsApps directory. Of course, I run into the issue with permissions, so I'm attempting to set permissions. While I can take ownership of the folder of the app, I cannot take ownership of specific files, everything in the ownership panel is greyed out. I realize that this is probably because the WindowsApps (or some other folder) is a folder that I haven't taken ownership of, but I'm not willing to break my system in the process of copying a single file, hence why I am attempting to copy it elsewhere. Is it possible I can use an external tool, an installer perhaps, to manually copy the files elsewhere?

Comment: You can try the command-line tool `robocopy.exe` (included in Windows 10) using the `/B` "backup" mode.

Comment: I have always had luck using WinZip or a similar application to view the contents of the folder.  However, what are you trying to achieve, by creating a copy of the file (you won’t be able to replace it).  You are right changing the permissions on WindowsApp will most definitely break all UWP applications.  You can install UWP to any drive you want but the permissions of WindowsApp won’t be any different.

Answer (score 0):

The method I find most convenient to examine or to copy *any* file, whatever the ownership, is to image the entire disk with a tool such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/).

Then [browse the image](http://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50080.aspx) with "Enable access to restricted folders," checked. Opening restricted data does not affect the image, so it's safe.

This also provides you with a full disk image, from which you can recover from malware or accidental damage to the disk. If you follow good practice and make images periodically, this is by far the easiest and safest way to manipulate restricted files.